# Unable to initialize mon0 interface

Tags: networking, wireless

When I started to recover the wifi key using reaver 1.4, after writing the command

```
root@kunjesh-Ideapad-Z570:~/reaver-1.4/src# reaver -i mon0 -b <USSID>
```

it is giving the error

```
Reaver v1.4 WiFi Protected Setup Attack Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>

[-] Failed to initialize interface 'mon0'
[-] Failed to recover WPA key
```

kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have created the directory `/etc/reaver`; otherwise things won't work.

Run `sudo airmon-ng start <INTERFACE>`.

Check that `iwconfig` shows the new interface (usually `mon0`) as being in Monitor mode. Managed will not work.

Run `aircheck-ng` and turn off any processes it tells you might be bad. Afterwards, use `airmon-ng stop mon0` and then `airmon-ng start wlan0` to recreate the (hopefully) monitoring interface.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, and after a few hours I realized that I'm not running reaver as root (run with `sudo`)

Answer (score 0):

mon0 is not a terribly likely name for a wireless interface. I know it's the one in their screenshot, that doesn't mean it's right for your system.

Try `ifconfig` to see what yours is called.

Incidentally, mine runs with `wlan0` BUT wants to be told my own mac address with `-m` switch, & doesn't like `mon0` at all.

Answer (score 0):

try **ifconfig**select the wireless network start with w as like wlan and command the following **sudo airmon-ng start wlan** to set interface as monitor mode be sure mon0 will enabled to monitor mode and capture the packet of mon0 by using this command **sudo airodump-ng mon0** and finally start the **sudo reaver -i mon0 -b bssid -a -N -vv -c 1**

Comment: OP is already running as root.